# Function 'GetRawInputDeviceList' could not be resolved

Tags: c++, eclipse, winapi, mingw

First trial of this function using:

1. ENV: Eclipse IDE for C/C++ & MinGW32 in Win10-64.
2. Reference:  [GetRawInputDeviceList function at Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getrawinputdevicelist)

My hello-world code is simple:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winuser.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
     cout << "USB Device Lister." << endl;
     UINT nDevices = 0; 
     PRAWINPUTDEVICELIST pRawInputDeviceList; 

     nHID = GetRawInputDeviceList(NULL, &nDevices, sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICELIST));
     cout << "found HID devices of "<< nHID << endl;
     return 0;
}
```

According to [Function definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getrawinputdevicelist), I have included the .h, still I got the errors:

```
error: 'PRAWINPUTDEVICELIST' was not declared in this scope
Function 'GetRawInputDeviceList' could not be resolved
```

[Some](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/mailman/mingw-users/thread/4AC37505.5070006@sbcglobal.net/) said it may need `#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501`, or mingw-x64, but it does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try also to define WINVER.
So you should add this before the `#include <windows.h>`

```
#define WINVER 0x0501  
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
```

Check this article out for more information: [Modifying WINVER and _WIN32_WINNT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/modifying-winver-and-win32-winnt).

PS. You don't have to include the winuser.h because it is already included by windows.h.

Comment: thanks, Elviss! exacly I was looking for and now the code run build successfully. IF I understood correctly that means my code now is from WinXP upwards compatible/valid?